# Measuring and proxies for leverage in the financial system

Tags: data, market-data, historical-data, leverage

It can be argued that the leverage - reflected by how much collateral people or firms need to put down to borrow and might lose if they fail to pay the loan back - used in the financial system is one of the quantities that proved to be fatal for the unfolding of the recent financial crises:
http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2012-12-09/if-we-don-t-measure-leverage-we-risk-more-crises.html

The more surprising it is that this quantity doesn't seem to be systematically measured.

**My question**
Are there any good proxies with some history available that could be used to get a grip on that quantity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends obviously on which specific leverage you attempt to measure but you can certainly build some sort of index from, for example, the below:

- Aggregate smoothed equity P/E ratio divergence from long term mean (in a sense it reflects how money is levered to buy stocks at multiples of their long term P/E mean).
- Broad money in circulation -> Money multipliers
- Amount of outstanding prime/Alt-As/subprime loans outstanding , HELs, commercial mortgage loans
- Discretionary consumer spending
- commercial machine leases (not sure whether there is public information out on that)
- Amount of business startups

I think it may be interesting to gather data on those and to compile an index, though I would estimate that it will not have much predictive power and is rather coincident or even slightly lagging.